# Highlight selected cell from hyperlink and maintain the other cell color

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have two sheets 1 & 2. I have a hyperlink in sheet 2 that will bring me to cell A2 in sheet 1 and highlight it in yellow. But at the same time it remove the color of cell A1 in sheet 1 too.

How I maintain the color of cell A1 in sheet 1?

I am using this vba code in sheet 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = red
    Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you still want to delete all the other colors inside the `.UsedRange` you could save the color of cell `A1` before deleting all the colors and then re-color `A1` afterwards. Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim i As Long, lngCI As Long
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    lngCI = Sheets(i).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    Sheets(i).UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
    Sheets(i).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCI
Next
ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = red 'Don't think this works, you could try .Color = RGBRed
Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: change -4142 to 2

However, this code raises a lot of questions. Why is it in a sheet instead of in a separate module? The line involving "red" is not being executed -- what do you intend? To avoid problems like this always include the following code at the top of your modules and it will let you know about the error.

```
Option Explicit
```

Other advice:

```
(2) use breaks to pause your code and then step through it as it executes
(3) use ranges to define the cells you are manipulating (e.g., dim r as range)
(4) use `r.select` as you debug your code to see which cell is being manipulated
```

Regarding (4), be careful about which sheet is activated at the time `.select` is executed -- and remember to remove all `.select` statements once done debugging.